# UIMenuController, Where does it take its target? Confused

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

When I use a `MenuController` without any customisation, I would Do this.

```
UIMenuController *menu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
[menu setTargetRect:self.frame inView:self.superview];
[menu setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
```

`menu` is a shared instance and I didn't specify the target.

From where the `UIMenuController` gets the `target` to perform default actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes you to the one which is first responder. Which is usually a textview or cell.

Comment: Thanks, Any quick pointer if I wanted to create such a component?

Comment: UIMenuController is one of the few things i hate the most. If you just want to show a custom menu on tableview/collection view, check its delegates and datasource methods.  https://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/john-szumski/getting-started-uimenucontroller-ios-5

Comment: also check http://iphonedev.tv/blog/2014/4/17/show-the-uimenucontroller-and-display-custom-edit-menus-for-uiviewcontroller-uitableviewcontroller-and-uicollectionview-on-ios-7